# Magento : Unable to Reindex Product Prices 1.9.2.4

Tags: product, magento-1, price, reindex

```
product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list 
does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at 
row 1' in /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): 
PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): 
Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): 
Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): 
Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): 
Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): 
Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6/ 
home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/
In
dexer/Price.php(455): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO 
`ca...')
#7 
/home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/
Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(379): 
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareTierPriceIndex()
#8 /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core
/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): 
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/mytheme/public_html/
app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): 
Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core/
Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/mytheme/public_html/shell/
indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/mytheme/public_html/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler-
>run()
  #13 {main}
```

Next exception

```
'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_tier_price` SELECT `tp`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, MIN(IF(tp.website_id = 0, ROUND(tp.value * cwd.rate, 4), tp.value)) FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tp`
 INNER JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg` ON tp.all_groups = 1 OR (tp.all_groups = 0 AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id)
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON tp.website_id = 0 OR tp.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id WHERE (cw.website_id != 0) GROUP BY `tp`.`entity_id`,
    `cg`.`customer_group_id`,
    `cw`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`)' in /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
    #0 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): 
    Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): 
    Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #2 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): 
    Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #3 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): 
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
    #4 /home/mytheme/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): 
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
    #5 
    /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core/
    Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(455): 
    Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
   #6 /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/
   core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(379): 
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareTierPriceIndex()
   #7 /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code
   /core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): 
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
   #8 /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): 
   Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
   #9 /home/mytheme/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): 
   Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
   #10 /home/mytheme/public_html/shell/indexer.php(168): 
   Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
   #11 /home/mytheme/public_html/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler-
   >run()
```

Comment: try reindex using command line like putty.

Comment: @JeevaRathinam I tried everything through SSH/Shell, I tried truncating everything possible ... still having the same issue of not being able to reindex product prices.